# error Parsing error: Unexpected token *

Tags: node.js, reactjs, import, lint

I have a React application trans-piled with babel and webpack. We have a large lint config that has never complained about our code until today.

I am getting `error Parsing error: Unexpected token *` pointing to files that have no imports whatsoever; e.g., `import * as name from './path/to/file';`

Also, I only get this error when on Node v6.7.0, but not when running my tests when on Node v8.0.0.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you end up resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try updating Babel [@babel/traverse/lib/path/evaluation.js shipped with `**` use causing test fails in Node 6 #7654](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7654)

Comment: This might have been it. But I'm not 100% sure. This morning builds work again. Thanks for the response.